# scheduled query execution in postgresql

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, psql

I am using postgresql 8.4 on a linux centos. I want to write a query that would be executed every hour for example. is there a way to do it using postgresql alone without writing a shell script and schedule it with a cron job?

Answer (score 1):

You could install [pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php) and schedule a [job](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/pgagent.html) using pgAdmin.

Offtopic: Version 8.4 is not supported anymore, consider an upgrade to a recent 9.* release.